# in dictionary (get need motherland student key valueType) error of expression is ambiguous without more context in swift diactionary

Tags: swift

```
var school : [[String:Any]] =               [[[["school1" : "devashya",
                                             "address" : "new_nikol",
                                             "student" : [[
                                             "name"   : "chirag",
                                             "roll_number" : "10"],
                                            ["name"    : "hiren",
                                             "roll_number" : "20"],
                                            ["name"     : "roshan",
                                             "roll_number"  : "30"]]]],
                                             [["school2" : "sankalpschool",
                                             "address"  : "nikol",
                                             "student" : [[
                                             "name"     : "keyur",
                                            "roll-number" : "40"],
                                            ["name"     : "mukesh",
                                            "roll-number" : "50"],
                                            ["name"     : "ravi",
                                            "roll-number" : "60"]]]],
                                            [["school3" : "motherland",
                                            "address"  : "naroda",
                                            "student"  : [[
                                            "name"     : "veer",
                                            "roll-number" : "70"],
                                            ["name"     : "nirav",
                                            "roll-number" : "80"],
                                            ["name"     : "rizvan",
                                            "roll-number" : "90"]]]],
                                            [["school4" : "vip",
                                            "address"  : "newnikol",
                                            "student" : [[
                                             "name"     : "vikky",
                                             "roll-number" : "100"],
                                             ["name"     : "alpesh",
                                             "roll-number" : "110"],
                                             ["name"     : "raavi",
                                             "roll-number"  : "120"]]]],
                                             [["school5" : "chanakya",
                                             "address" : "sardarchowk",
                                             "student" : [[
                                             "name"    : "mayur",
                                             "roll-number" : "130"],
                                             ["name"    : "vrinkesh",
                                             "roll-number" : "140"],
                                             ["name"    : "annav",
                                              "roll-number" : "150"]]]]]]


var classroom = "motherland"
for hostel in school
    {
    
    if let name = hostel["student"] as? [[String: Any]]
    {
        for Arr in name
        {

            print(Arr)
        }
       
    }
    
}
```

Comment: **school** as you are showing us, is not`var school: [[String : Any]]` it is `var school: [[[[String : Any]]]]`
Fix this first, then proceed with your `for hostel in school {...}` loop.
 In other words you have too many [[[[[[[ and ]]]]]]]

Comment: Please write an explanation of your issue and what you are asking in the body of the post instead of trying to do it in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of issue with your `school` variable.

Replace `school` with the following and try your code.

```
var school : [[String:Any]] = [
                                ["school1" : "devashya", "address" : "new_nikol", "student" :
                                    [[ "name" : "chirag", "roll_number" : "10"],
                                     ["name" : "hiren", "roll_number" : "20"],
                                     ["name" : "roshan", "roll_number" : "30"]]],
                                ["school2" : "sankalpschool", "address" : "nikol", "student" :
                                    [[ "name" : "keyur", "roll-number" : "40"],
                                     ["name" : "mukesh", "roll-number" : "50"],
                                     ["name" : "ravi", "roll-number" : "60"]]],
                                ["school3" : "motherland", "address" : "naroda", "student" :
                                    [[ "name" : "veer", "roll-number" : "70"],
                                     ["name" : "nirav", "roll-number" : "80"],
                                     ["name" : "rizvan", "roll-number" : "90"]]],
                                ["school4" : "vip", "address" : "newnikol", "student" :
                                    [[ "name" : "vikky", "roll-number" : "100"],
                                     ["name" : "alpesh", "roll-number" : "110"],
                                     ["name" : "raavi", "roll-number" : "120"]]],
                                ["school5" : "chanakya", "address" : "sardarchowk", "student" :
                                    [[ "name" : "mayur", "roll-number" : "130"],
                                     ["name" : "vrinkesh", "roll-number" : "140"],
                                     ["name" : "annav", "roll-number" : "150"]]]
                            ]
```

```
let names = school.filter{$0["school"] as! String == "motherland"}.first?.filter{$0.key == "student"}.values
```

Comment: i need only mootherland student name and rollnumber .... this code is showing all school student name and roll number ...

Comment: I just fixed your school variable which had multiple unwanted brackets. Did not fixed your code.

Comment: ```school.filter{$0["school"] as! String == "motherland"}.first?.filter{$0.key == "student"}.values``` this may give u the required output

Comment: var classroom = "vip"
for hostel in school
    {

    if let name = hostel["student"] as? [[String : Any]]


   {

        for Arr in name
        {

            print(Arr)
        }

    }

}which place i put if condition...???

Comment: no need of the if condition just run my code and check the output

Comment: not get student roll-number 
my code is hear
var qqq = "annav"

for hostel in school
{

    let name = hostel["name"] ?? " "
    print(name)
    if name as! String == qqq
    {
        let aaa = hostel["roll-number"] ?? " "
       print(aaa)
   }

}